# How realistic is it to use a Raspberry Pi 3 as a light desktop PC?

Tags: memory, cpu, raspberry-pi, desktop-computer, raspbian

The Raspberry Pi is obviously not the first thing which comes to mind for building a desktop machine - if for no other reason, then at least for lacking relevant connectors. Also, it's been quite a few years since a 1 GHz chip with 1 GB of memory could bear the load of typical desktop environments.

However, the specs are nothing to scoff at - it has a quad-core CPU after all - and the price is quite low. On the software side, I know that it's possible to run older/lighter desktop environments quite well on older hardware, even as far back as a P3, P4 or Athlon.

So, my question is as follows. Suppose I:

- Take a Raspberry Pi 3 (with some memory card)
- Connect a (powered) USB hub to my raspberry Pi, which allows me to connect my keboard, a mouse and an HDD or SSD.
- Am a light desktop user: Browsing the web, reading email, editing documents
- Don't mind running Linux rather than Windows (e.g. [Raspbian](https://www.raspbian.org/)), and the lack/incompatibility  of many pieces of software for/with the Pi.
- Have a monitor that's about 2K, not 4K.

... can I expect a reasonable, tolerable desktop computing experience from the Pi 3 as my desktop? What would be the most salient annoyances?

Comment: @Mokubai: Could you suggest an amendment to this question which would make it less opinion-based?

Comment: Not really. The problem is that what is "reasonable" or "tolerable" is a highly subjective thing. What one person considers reasonable is an utter nightmare for someone else. There is also the problem that any answers here will, by necessity, have to recommend some operating system or window manager or application set that "works kinda well" which is almost software recs. I would expect a less opinion based question to say "I have an RPi running <wibbleOs> and connected to <shonkyHardware>. It runs like a dog doing job <leetDesktopPublishing>. Is there some specific reason this is so slow?"

Comment: Mokubai: How about if I ask about people who have tried doing this whether they  "lasted" or gave it up?

Comment: Again you're back to asking about highly subjective personal experiences. Some people just can't be bothered with things the moment they get slightly difficult or glitchy while others would follow the "Never give up, never surrender!" mantra. An RPi is not particularly expensive, and anyone with access to a desktop system has all the tools necessary to try it out for themselves. Or if they have to buy a keyboard, monitor and so on then they should probably have just tried a  Chromebook in a shop and saved money...

Comment: I get that you spent time formulating this question and it shows because it is detailed, clear and well asked and apart from soliciting opinions it *is* a good quality question. It's just not a question that fits because it would solicit opinions and discussions rather than having solid workable answers. If you were asking if it could work at all then that would have a definitive answer of "yes", but "how well does it work?" Is just too fuzzy.. this is maybe a question for discusstion via [chat].

Comment: Maybe make it less broad by  asking for specific usage on selected os or test by using vm with cpu execution cap, iops limit and similar amounts of ram. not exactly same but should at least tell you something.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest running linux with a light weight desktop enviroment such as [Xfce](https://xfce.org/).

But over wise yes the user experience is definitely tolerable (perhaps with a little patience) especially on the newer models. Microsoft even released a [slimmed down version of windows 10](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/windows-10-for-iot/) for the pi2/3.

Answer (score 0):

You would not be the first to use a Raspberry Pi as computer. True you will indeed need a suitable OS and it will not be the fastest, but it is certainly doable to surf the internet and possibly even use it as a Terminal Services client.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the experience? I mean, of course it will _work_ , the question is how much will I suffer.

Comment: I'd say it is comparable with a 6 year old computer.

Comment: depends a lot what you're gonna do with it. some web pages with a lot of dynamic content might make it feel like a punishment but most lightweight browsing, text editing and even some games will work just fine.